Smbcacls faster connection
I am having issue with smbcacls performance. I have extracted the code from the utils source to create a custom smbcacls function. What I am having issue is this
work flow is this
talloc_stackframe
cli_session_creds_init(...)
cli_full_connection_creds(...)
cli_ntcreate(...)
cli_query_security_descriptor(...)

cli_full_connection_creds takes most of the performance, and is ofcourse slow. I am unable to resuse the cli_state from the cli_full_connection_creds, as for the next entry the cli_ntcreate fails with STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND (0xC0000034).
Is it possible to reuse cli_state?
